# How can I add a \n + a ">" and a numerical header to separate lines every 200 characters?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have this continuos sequence and  I would like to add a \n every 200 characters and a > for separating these groups. I guess taht using a sed and a awk could help but Im new in this..

This would be my input:

```
ATACAGTTGGGTTTGGTTGGATCTTCGTCGGTATTTTTATTGGGTTAATTCTCTGGTTTTTCATCAACCGCGCCAGCGTCAGAGCGAACAGGCAGGTTGAATTACTTGAGTCTATCGACCAGAAATTATCAAAAATAGTAGATCCAAACTTCGAGGCAAATAACAAAGACCAGTCGAAAGAAAACTACCTTGAAGAAGCATGGGAAAACAGCATTCAGCGGTGGCTTATTCCTGCTAAGGATGTTGGCCGCATTCATGCTGAGCACAACCTCGACGGCCTGCTGAGGGGCGATTCGGCATCCCGCGCTGCCTTTATGAAGGCAATGGGAGAGGCAGGGCTACGCACCATCAACGAGATGCGACGAACGGACAACCTCCCGCCATTGCCGGGTGGCGATGTGAAATGGGAACCGCGAACATGCCTGCACATCCGTTTGTGCGACCCGCTTACGATACTCGCGAGGAAGAGGCCGCCAGCGTCGCCATTGCCAGGATGAATCAGGCTATTGATGAGGTATTGAGCAAGTGAATGAAGATAATATCTACGCCTTGCTTTCTCCCCTGGCAGAAGGACGGGTATATCCCTATGTTGCGCCATTA
```

This is my expected output (no commas for >):

```
>1
ATACAGTTGGGTTTGGTTGGATCTTCGTCGGTATTTTTATTGGGTTAATTCTCTGGTTTTTCATCAACCGCGCCAGCGTCAGAGCGAACAGGCAGGTTGAATTACTTGAGTCTATCGACCAGAAATTATCAAAAATAGTAGATCCAAACTTCGAGGCAAATAACAAAGACCAGTCGAAAGAAAACTACCTTGAAGAAGCA
>2
TGGGAAAACAGCATTCAGCGGTGGCTTATTCCTGCTAAGGATGTTGGCCGCATTCATGCTGAGCACAACCTCGACGGCCTGCTGAGGGGCGATTCGGCATCCCGCGCTGCCTTTATGAAGGCAATGGGAGAGGCAGGGCTACGCACCATCAACGAGATGCGACGAACGGACAACCTCCCGCCATTGCCGGGTGGCGATGT
>3
GAAATGGGAACCGCGAACATGCCTGCACATCCGTTTGTGCGACCCGCTTACGATACTCGCGAGGAAGAGGCCGCCAGCGTCGCCATTGCCAGGATGAATCAGGCTATTGATGAGGTATTGAGCAAGTGAATGAAGATAATATCTACGCCTTGCTTTCTCCCCTGGCAGAAGGACGGGTATATCCCTATGTTGCGCCATTA
```

Any advice? Thanks in advance

A.

Comment: I found this:

sed -e "s/.\{400\}/&\n/g" < input > output

I only need to add the >

Comment: So, `sed -e 's/.\{200\}/>&\n/g' < input > output`?  Is this supposed to be in fasta format? If so, the input seems to lack header lines.

Comment: @Kusalananda you were right, Ive changed the txt :)

Comment: That sed command won't add a count after each `>`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment @EdMorton :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution which does avoid potentially heavy parsers and regular expressions is the following pipeline, which should work on every UNIX system, as it uses only POSIX features with the XSI option:

```
tr -d '\n' | dd cbs=200 conv=unblock | nl -n ln | tr '\t' '\n' | paste -d '>\n' /dev/null - -
```

You need to supply the file to the standard input, e.g. by prepending `cat file |` in front of the command for data stored in `file`.

The command removes the trailing newline with `tr`, splits the lines in chuncks of 200 bytes, numbers each line with the number at the left side separated from the data by the tab character, which is replaced by the following command into a newline to make the output friendly for `paste`, which adds the `>` character in front of the number.

Comment: This works great! I used your command like this

cat  input | tr -d '\n' | dd cbs=200 conv=unblock | nl -n ln | tr '\t' '\n' | paste -d '>\n' /dev/null - - > output

Comment: would this also work in big files? like 3-4GB?

Comment: I would say so, yes, although the conversion might take some time. The data is simply streamed through the pipeline in blocks with no need to buffer all data, so except for overflow in the line counter after *really* much ljnes and possible too large files due to system limitations itself, nothing should prevent this to work on large files.

Answer (score 2):

With `perl` you can initialize the RS to \200 to read 200  bytes at a time. Assuming your file has chars same as bytes.

```
$ perl -ne '
    BEGIN { $/ = \200; $\ = "\n" }
    chop if /\n/;
    last if /^$/;
    ++$k; print s/^/>$k\n/r;
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='.{200}' 'RT{print ">" NR ORS RT}' file
>1
ATACAGTTGGGTTTGGTTGGATCTTCGTCGGTATTTTTATTGGGTTAATTCTCTGGTTTTTCATCAACCGCGCCAGCGTCAGAGCGAACAGGCAGGTTGAATTACTTGAGTCTATCGACCAGAAATTATCAAAAATAGTAGATCCAAACTTCGAGGCAAATAACAAAGACCAGTCGAAAGAAAACTACCTTGAAGAAGCA
>2
TGGGAAAACAGCATTCAGCGGTGGCTTATTCCTGCTAAGGATGTTGGCCGCATTCATGCTGAGCACAACCTCGACGGCCTGCTGAGGGGCGATTCGGCATCCCGCGCTGCCTTTATGAAGGCAATGGGAGAGGCAGGGCTACGCACCATCAACGAGATGCGACGAACGGACAACCTCCCGCCATTGCCGGGTGGCGATGT
>3
GAAATGGGAACCGCGAACATGCCTGCACATCCGTTTGTGCGACCCGCTTACGATACTCGCGAGGAAGAGGCCGCCAGCGTCGCCATTGCCAGGATGAATCAGGCTATTGATGAGGTATTGAGCAAGTGAATGAAGATAATATCTACGCCTTGCTTTCTCCCCTGGCAGAAGGACGGGTATATCCCTATGTTGCGCCATTA
```

Comment: Hi @Ed Morton,  For some reason it works great with my example but if I use your line for a similar but bigger file  I get:


>1


>2


>3


>4


>5


>6


>7


>8


>9

Comment: @EdMortron, you were right and the format from the input file was not correct! Thank you!

Comment: FYI upvoting answers that help you is customary on this forum, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352126/is-it-the-correct-way-to-upvote-an-answer.

Comment: Yes..I just found that I cant have more than one preferred answer. Thanks for the tip

Comment: You can only **accept** one answer but you can upvote as many as you like.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `awk`:

```
awk -v FPAT='.{200}' '{ while(++num<=NF) print ">"num RS $num; }' infile
```

Above command will only work when your line is always in module of 200, if not, and that is less or more you will need to print out the remained or if line was less than 200 characters also:

```
awk -v FPAT='.{200}' '{ while(++num<=NF) print ">"num RS $num; };
END{
    if (length($0)%200)
        print ">" num RS substr($0, int(length($0)/200)*200+1, length($0)%200);
}' infile
```